# Randomizing Thread sleep

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have the following code within the run method of a runnable:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    final Random r=new Random(1000);
    int acquired=0;
    try{
        while(acquired < 1){
            for(int i=0;i<sems.length;i++){
                    if(sems[i].tryAcquire()){
                            System.out.println("Acquired for " + i);
                            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt());
                            sems[i].increment();
                            sems[i].release();
                            acquired=1;
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(InterruptedException x){}

}
```

I keep getting the following exception a few moments into the execution:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.bac.jp.fourteenth$1.run(fourteenth.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.bac.jp.fourteenth$1.run(fourteenth.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However,if I use a Thread.sleep(1000) the program runs fine.
Why am I not able to randomize the pause using java Random?

Comment: A negative number is also a random number and `Thread.sleep(-ve value)` is not permitted.

Comment: Yeah yeah... If only they would read the exceptions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `r.nextInt(1000)`// returns a number from 0-999... this fixs the negative return problem

Comment: Correct - i got confused between the nextInt() variations.Didnt realize that the no-argument one behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

The Random number generator have generated a negative number and when you pass a negative value as an argument to `Thread.sleep()` you get an instant exception.

Answer (score 1):

replace `Thread.sleep(r.nextInt());` with `Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(1000));`

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) you will see the following:

```
nextInt

public int nextInt()
Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number 
generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is 
pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 232 possible int values are produced with 
(approximately) equal probability.

The method nextInt is implemented by class Random as if by:

 public int nextInt() {
   return next(32);
 }
Returns:
the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number 
generator's sequence
```

You will want to use `nextInt(int n)` as follows

```
nextInt

public int nextInt(int n)
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the 
specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The 
general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly 
generated and returned. All n possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal 
probability.
```